# How to get a List of Integers from a Property when another property exists within a List<int>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Trying to get a return value of `List<int>` where one variable is a class, with properties `ID` and `ParentID`, and another variable is an `List<int>` with all Parent IDs in there.  I want to return all IDs from the class variable that have match inside of `List<int>` variable where `ParentID` exists.

For example:

_SubCategories = class with 2 properties:  `ParentID` and `ID` (Both of Type Int32)
_ParentCategoryIDs = `List<int>` with a full list of all Parent IDs.

I need to loop through all `_ParentCategoryIDs`, where they exist in `_SubCategories.ParentID` and get all of the IDs for each `ParentID` from `_SubCategories`, and have it populate in a `List<int>`.

I'm struggling with how to do this exactly, basically, I than want to convert this to a string delimited by a pipe character |, something like this:

```
string.Join("|", _SubCategories.ConvertAll<int>(v => v.ParentID)
                               .Intersect(_ParentCategoryIDs).Distinct());
```

So, it would need to output all IDs from _SubCategories where `ParentID` is in `_ParentCategoryIDs`.  Feeling a bit stupid on trying to get this to work...

Am thinking I need a `SelectMany` and `Where` somewhere here...  Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Can you clean it up a bit. Show your class definitions.

Comment: Just updated question, not sure what you need to know.  Both properties are of type `int` within the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds fairly straightforward, unless Ive misunderstood the question

```
var matched = _SubCategories.Where(sc => _ParentCategoryIDs.Contains(sc.ParentID))
                      .Select(sc => sc.ID)
                      .ToList();
```

Then you can join this with pipes:

```
var result = String.Join("|",matched);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.  And wrapped it inside `String.Join(...)`  Cheers :)  Feeling dumb, cause going from ASP.NET to PHP to ASP.NET to PHP and over and over again, forget basic things!

Comment: @Jamiec - +1 :) Now, can you post the `Type` you have used, curious to know :P

Comment: @RahulSingh - no need, I just took the question as is. A List of objects with properties `ParentID` and `ID` and a `List<int>` containing ParentId's to match.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what yo mean (but try this):-

```
 List<int> result = categories.Where(x => x.ParenttIds.Contains(x.subCats.ParentID))
                              .Select(x => x.subCats.ID).ToList();
```

Where i have used following inputs and type:-

```
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>
           {
               new Category { subCats = new _SubCategories { ID =1, ParentID = 4}, ParenttIds = new List<int> { 2,4,7}},
               new Category { subCats = new _SubCategories { ID =2, ParentID = 2}, ParenttIds = new List<int> { 4,3,8}},
               new Category { subCats = new _SubCategories { ID =3, ParentID = 8}, ParenttIds = new List<int> { 2,8,4}}
           };

public class Category
    {
        public _SubCategories subCats { get; set; }
        public List<int> ParenttIds { get; set; }
    }

    public class _SubCategories
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ParentID  { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Not my dv, but im confused by how you think the OP's class layout looks. You'd be better waiting for them to clarify that than just guessing and potentially confusing them more.

Comment: @Jamiec - I agree OP didn't posted it well, Inspite of describing so much he could have just shown us the class definitions :)  Anyways, I picked him from this para - `one variable is a class, with properties ID and ParentID, and another variable is an List<int> with all Parent IDs in there. I want to return all IDs from the class variable that have match inside of List<int> variable where ParentID exists.`

Comment: Yeah, I dont have a clue how you turned that paragraph into what you have.

Comment: @Jamiec - I created `Category` class and put one variable class as `_SubCategories` with two properties and other one as `List<int>`. But definitely its OPs responsibility to ask questions properly rather than keep others guessing :)

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda expressions:

```
int id = 1; //ID of parent (Category)
List<SubCategory> results =  _SubCategories.FindAll(x => x.ParentId == id); //returns all subcat with parent id = 1
```